How can I filter Query Loop to show only posts in current category?
I am migrating a site from a page builder to a block theme.
In my main post template I want to list other posts in the same category as the current post, excluding the current post itself.
In the page builder, filtering the equivalent blog post list was simple a case of choosing 'current category' from a dropdown, but it's not supported in the default Wordpress Query Loop block.
I was hoping to build a block variation for the Query Loop block but have been unable to work out what I need to do to automatically filter the results in the block based on the current post's category.
wp.blocks.registerBlockVariation(
'core/query',
{
    name: 'related-latest-posts',
    title: 'Related Latest Posts',
    description: 'Displays related posts',
    attributes: {
        postsToShow: 3
    },
    query: {
        postType: 'post',
        postStatus: 'publish',
        orderby: 'date',
        order: 'desc',
        perPage: 3
    }
}

);

Curious if you ever figured this one out? I'm running into a similar situation.

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review
